# Are there any technical limitations against adding anonymous functions in C?

Tags: c, functions, identifiers

An anonymous function behaves the same as a regular function with no identifier attached. One could be passed as a callback or stored in a function pointer variable. In C++ they can be written as follows:

```
int (*add)(int, int) = [](int x, int y) -> int {return x+y;};
```

However in pure C there is no compound-literal style syntax to create anonymous functions:

```
int (*add)(int, int) = (int(int x, int y)){return x+y;};
```

One must clutter the global namespace to use `bsearch()`, `qsort()`, or construct an array of many functions.

I realize C is older than C++ and did not always have compound literals (anonymous variables) in the first place. However those were added in C99 but anonymous functions were not. Not even in C23.

Are there technical limitations or other disadvantages that I do not know of that prevents identifier-less functions?

Comment: C is over 50 years old and needed to run in reasonable time on that hardware. A lot of the answers to why it is the way it is were to make the compiler more efficient.

Comment: @user16217248 eh, usually you can flag it instead, and you should. Just feel free to flag any comment when they are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Closures are complicated

C is and always has been a simple language, and it tries to remain that way even today. If you wanted to add the ability to make simple non-closing functions as local variables, that's easy and wouldn't affect the semantics of the language in the slightest. A non-closing function would simply compile to a top-level `static` function with a generated name and would only be accessible inside of the scope it was defined in.

However, generally when people want anonymous functions, what they really want is *closures*. Closures can use local variables in the surrounding scope, in addition to the data globally available in the current file. That's what allows tricks like

```
def add_to_each(lst, number):
    return map(lambda x: x + number, lst)
```

to work. The `lambda` here *closes* around the variable `number`. It's no longer just an ordinary function in the machine sense of the word; now it's a function plus some extra state.

In C++, if you create a lambda that doesn't close around any variables, it's guaranteed to be available as a function pointer, i.e. a plain old ordinary C++98-style function. But if you need a nontrivial closure, then C++ does magic to make a strange object that just works the way you expect. That object's type is no longer `int(*)(int, int)`. Its type is in fact special-made just for this situation, and you can't refer to it by name (though it is convertible to `std::function<int(int, int)>`, which is another piece of C++ magic). All of this is fine in C++, which is "C plus insane high-level shenanigans". But C is designed to be simple and predictable, so the language avoids adding all of this code generation for the same reason templates were never added to C: it would just add so much complexity.

Comment: In C++, even non-capturing lambda's have a unique type. They're only *convertible* to function pointers, but every lambda type is a class type.

Answer (score 3):

[Apple did it](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)), so the answer is obviously *No*, there is no technical limitation.

Apple added a non-standard feature called *Blocks* to their implementation of C in order to support easy use of the *Grand Central Dispatch* concurrency mechanism. Unlike GCC's non-standard *nested functions*, which cannot be called after the outer function ends, Apple's Blocks are proper closures which can close over their surrounding environment and can outlive their outer function.

Comment: Looking at [the implementation details](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html), it's basically `std::function` as a compiler built-in. Block objects have constructors and destructors that are invoked automatically by the compiler and allocate heap space, etc. Of course it's possible (how could it not be?) but it's rather un-C-like, I'd say.